# Comma separator for numbers with 4 or 5 digits?

Tags: punctuation, numbers

Having gone to school back in the mid 80's to the early 90's, I pretty much sucked at math and English. However, one of the things I remembered was that the first comma in a large number was not inserted unless the number had at least 5 digits.

Example -

100

1000

10,000

100,000

1,000,000

However, I never really tried looking that up until now, when it came up in discussion. I can't seem to find a reference to this 'rule' or guidance anymore, and am wondering if - in my old age - I'm just completely making that up now.

Comment: I've seen plenty of instances of, e.g. "$1,000". I've never heard of this "Wait til the fifth digit" rule.

Comment: It's an SI rule, but SI uses spaces as thousand-separators.

Comment: What research did you do on your own before asking here? If you cite where you've looked, other people won't look the same places.

Comment: Andrew Leach has answered your question.  He assumes that you know SI means Système International, the French organization that is the "final word" on scientific units.  In my experience and outside of the sciences, the comma persists in US English.  That said, computer applications will almost always expect the SI usage.  It is an evolving issue, but the "space over comma" faction will almost certainly win.

Comment: Interesting, thanks guys. I specifically remember it being a comma and not a space, and NOT for currency (@danBron's comment) - just specific text like "Today, 45,522 people celebrated their birthday, and tomorrow only 4234 people will."

The two main sites I checked were the AMA and [Rules for Writing Numbers](http://www.grammarbook.com/numbers/numbers.asp). I did come across the SI site as well, and saw that it had referenced spaces. 

I'm guessing that sometime between learning in school, and now, I got the two merged in my head, thinking they were one and the same.

Comment: In the UK every third digit is separated by a comma (although the practice is losing popularity due to many countries interpreting a comma as a decimal point)

Comment: It's purely a matter of "style".  In documents of a scientific or financial nature it's best to insert separators beginning at 1,000, to avoid confusion, but in less rigorous circumstances the comma is often omitted to reduce clutter.

Comment: Not only is the comma optional when *writing* numbers with 4 digits (to the left of the decimal point), but numbers of 4 digits are often *read* as double-digit hundreds instead of single-digit thousands.  For example, 3400 can be read as "thrity-four hundred" instead of "three thousand, four hundred."  See rule 6 on this page: https://www.grammarbook.com/numbers/numbers.asp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a question of style, and, if you are writing
in a structured environment (e.g., school or work),
you should follow whatever standards and guidelines
are in effect in your situation. 
But, as one somewhat official example,
the [U.S. Government Printing Office (GPO) Style Manual](https://www.gpo.gov/fdsys/pkg/GPO-STYLEMANUAL-2008/pdf/GPO-STYLEMANUAL-2008.pdf) (a 467-page PDF)
says, in Chapter 12. Numerals, section 12.14 Punctuation (page 289)
the following:

> The comma is used in a number containing four or more digits,
>   except in serial numbers, common and decimal fractions, astronomical
>   and military time, and kilocycles and meters of not more
>   than four figures pertaining to radio.

although in preceding paragraphs they have indicated
that commas should *not* be used in years (e.g., 2017).

Section 12.7 indicates that street addresses (e.g., “1727 St. Clair Avenue”)
and telephone numbers are considered to be serial numbers
(and thus should not have commas —
presumably, even if they have *more* than four digits
(and, yes, I know of a place where they have five-digit street numbers)). 
It goes without saying that this also applies to postal ZIP codes.

Oddly, they say that “a 1,100-percent increase”
and “an 1100-percent increase” are both acceptable. 
They don’t explain; I guess the rationale is that
“1,100” would be pronounced “one thousand one hundred”
and “1100” would be pronounced “eleven hundred”.

And (again, without any explanation) they offer
“Dow Jones average of 10500.76” as an example of correct usage.

Comment: Gonna go ahead and mark the answer. My research didn't find the GPO links before, that's good to see. +1 for the difference in readings of '1100-percent', too..!

Answer (score 2):

I've seen this "rule" before. In my opinion, it is a stupid rule.

"2017 graduates": is 2017 a year or a head count? Without that "rule", you could write:
"2017 graduates" (2017 is a year)
or
"2,017 graduates" (2,017 is a head count)

Also, in tables, the numbers will not line up right if you include commas in some numbers ≥ 1000 but not others.

```
  9998
  9999
10,000
10,001
```

versus

```
 9,998
 9,999
10,000
10,001
```

Comment: Strange rule. As much as I know there are no rules how a delimiter must be used.